# php - Query equivalent to "startsWith" in php Parse.com library

Tags: php, parse-platform

Hi I've just started using the third party PHP library for 'Parse.com' . Is there a query equivalent to "startsWith" query in the PHP library ? I've gone through [this library](https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library)  but couldn't figure out if there was a query that matched it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact syntax of this actual PHP library, but you should be able to use its function;

```
public function whereRegex($key,$value,$options='')
```

...searching for `^myvalue` to find all values starting with "myvalue".